# Mocking a RestTemplate that returns a List in Spring v1.5.14.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

I have this RestTemplate that I want to mock

```
ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> deliveryResponse =
                    restTemplate.exchange(link.getHref(),
                            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Hotel>>() {
                            });
```

but I don't know if it is possible. I've tried

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("delivery"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(RequestEntity.class), eq(Object.class)))
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Hotel>>(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: Use `any()` instead of `any(HttpEntity.class)` as the last one does not cover `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`any(Class)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-)

> Matches any object of given type, excluding nulls.

---

[`any()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any)

> Matches anything, including nulls and varargs.

---

So as previously suggested changing your test code to the following will solve your issue.

As `ParameterizedTypeReference` can not be instantiated because it is an abstract class, you could return a mock instead and define the needed behaviour on it.

```
List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();

ResponseEntity response = Mockito.mock(ResponseEntity.class);
Mockito.when(response.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
Mockito.when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(hotels);

when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("delivery"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(), eq(Object.class)))
    .thenReturn(response);
```

Comment: I got this error with the soluction proposed: 'ParameterizedTypeReference' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: Yes, that is an abstract class that can not be instantiated. So you question was not about the mock (not matching), but how about the return was supposed to be written? -- Maybe you can clarify what exactly you need to have returned and what your code is doing afterwards with the `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: I've replaced the `return` value with a mock instead. You can define the behavious as your code requires it to be. If you need help with that feel free to add some more code to your question.